# SELECT all rows by one field and different values

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

Please help me with this SQL Query.

I have a table "`objects`". In that table exist field agent. On web site my agent `ID` is "7".

also I have array with ID's of other agents.

I want to make one SQL query to SELECT all objects FROM objects WHERE agent=7 and also I want to select objects where agent = 4, 5, 8, 9 (id's 4 5 8 9 exist in my array "`IDs`")

NOW I have `SELECT * FROM objects WHERE agent=7 AND status='$st' ORDER BY ID DESC` but it select only my objects, I need include in this request another objects of another agents by their ids

Comment: Sorry if this sounds dumb, but wouldn't removing `agent=7` fix it?

Comment: Or simply extend it by adding `OR agent=4 OR agent=…`?

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL? They have different syntax..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IN clause to fetch all the objects

```
SELECT * FROM objects WHERE agent IN ('4', '5', '7','8','9') 
AND status='$st' ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: That's it! Thx, i forgot about IN

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question a few times to actually get somewhere, I think you are asking to get a range of `agents` using their IDs.

You can do that by using SQL Code like this:

```
SELECT * FROM objects WHERE agent IN ('4','5','7','8','9') AND status='$st' ORDER BY id DESC
```

You could also use `WHERE agent > 4`

Answer (score 0):

Use below SQL Query

```
SELECT * FROM objects WHERE agent IN ('4', '5', '7','8','9') AND status='$st' ORDER BY id DESC
```

All the best!

Comment: and don't forget to Up-vote this answer if this works for you.